How to intercept outgoing Spring WebClient Request from a service during a test
In order to reduce impact produced by some E2E test, I have to modify the body of a REST request during the test.
The actual code follow this logic :
E2E test call endpoint with POST then the service call an external REST API, and it's the body of this request I have to modify.
I can't modify the code of the service, only the test.
Actually, the test use a WebTestClient to mock authentification :
class someE2ETest {
private WebTestClient rest;
...
 @BeforeEach
  void loadAuthentication() throws JSONException {
    rest =
      WebTestClient
        .bindToServer()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + localPort)
        .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+authentication.jwt().getToken().getTokenValue())
        .filter(modifySfRequestBody())      
        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .build();

    when(authenticationContext.getTokenValue()).thenReturn(authentication.token());
    when(authenticationContext.getMatricule()).thenReturn("PT080");

    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(new MockHttpServletRequest()));

    deleteRequestWithDeclarationId();
    deleteRequestWithUtId();
  }
...
}

The service use a WebClient :
public class MyAPI {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MyAPI (WebClient webClient,  HttpClient httpClient) {
      this.webClient = webClient.mutate().build();
  }
  public RestRequestResponse createRequest(RestRequestCreate request) {
    return webClient
      .post()
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(URI).build())
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
      .retrieve()
      .onStatus(....)
      .bodyToMono(RestRequestResponse.class)
      .blockOptional()
      .orElseThrow(...);
  }
}



I've tried to use filter in the WebTestClient, but the function is called only during call from test to service (and not service to api).
